# generate animations randomly on button click in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lottie

I have three lottie player json animation files - **congratulations1.json**, **congratulations2.json** and **congratulations3.json** The animations are as follows:

**congratulations1:**

```
<lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer1"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
```

**congratulations2:**

```
<lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer2"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations2.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
```

**congratulations3:**

```
<lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer3"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations3.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
```

**Note:** **The path of the json files are mentioned in src in those lottie-player tag.**

I want to display them randomly when a single button is clicked.

**Things I have done:**

I have taken three variables for each of those three animations. Variables are - **showPlayer1**, **showPlayer2** and **showPlayer3**.
I have kept them inside an array named **showPlayer** and set their values as false. I dont know if my procedure is correct or not.
What to do next I have no idea.

**My array:**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPlayer: [
        (showPlayer1 = false),
        (showPlayer2 = false),
        (showPlayer3 = false),
      ],
    };
  },
```

I have done upto this. What to include inside the button tag to display those three animations randomly from an array, I have no idea. Please help.

**Updated code:**

```
<div class="justify-content-center anim">
        <lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer === 1"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
      </div>
      <div class="justify-content-center anim">
        <lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer === 2"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations_2.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
      </div>
      <div class="justify-content-center anim">
        <lottie-player
          v-if="showPlayer === 3"
          class="justify-content-center"
          src="../../../congratulations_3.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've shown below there are serveral other ways to achieve this. But if you want to do it like you suggest I would not use showPlayer as an array of boolean but rather as a number.

```
<template>
<div v-if="showPlayer === 1"> DIV 1 </div>
<div v-if="showPlayer === 2"> DIV 3 </div>
<div v-if="showPlayer === 3"> DIV 3 </div>
<button @click="onRandomButtonPress">Random!</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showPlayer: 1
    };
  },
methods: {
onRandomButtonPress() {
  this.showPlayer = Math.floor(Math.random()*3 + 1);
},
}
</script>
```

There are multiple ways to deal with this. If you only want to use one component and toggle the source you can do something like this:
First, set the src of your components to a variable:

```
<lottie-player
          class="justify-content-center"
          :src="animationSrc"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 300px; height: 300px"
          loop
          controls
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player
        >;
```

Set an array with the strings you have in your data() like this:

```
  animations: [
    '../../../congratulations.json',
    '../../../congratulations2.json',
    '../../../congratulations3.json',
  ],
  animationSrc: ''
```

Then set a methon for the randomButton like this:

```
onRandomButtonPress() {
  this.animationSrc = this.animations[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.animations.length)];
},
```

I have hacked a codesandbox together real quick:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dijkstra-o7ety?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

You can also use the :is attribute in vue to load a dynamic component and set in code which component you want to be loaded.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: Inside lottie player tag, in src, it was the path of the json file. The animations are different not same. By the way, not working. Show me any alternative way please.

Comment: I've added an example on how to do it with v-if and loading the components based on a component state. Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked......... Your latest code worked.